# Java Inheritance in Djinni supported?

Tags: android, djinni

Does Djinni (dropbox) supports inheritance ? Following [this](https://github.com/dropbox/djinni/pull/270)
description and example. I have tried to use inheritance but it gives a syntax error. I am not sure if that's all required or am i missing something.

**Parent Class:**

```
 Explorer = interface +c {
 fetchItems(folder: Folder);
 setDelegate(delegate: ExplorerDelegate);
}
```

**Child Class:**

```
FTPExplorer  = interface extends Explorer +c { // Error here
  fetchItems(folder: Folder);
}
```

**Error**: "{" expected but `e' found

I can generate my wrapper successfully after removing extends Explorer. Please let me know if i am missing something, as i couldn't find any detailed example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, djinni does not support inheritance for now. There is a pull request for that ( https://github.com/dropbox/djinni/pull/270 ) but it seems to be abandoned.